# Why can the ternary operator ?: not be used as a statement?

Tags: c#

Instead of using `if`, I attempt to use `?:` operator as follows. However, the compiler produces errors. Why can the ternary operator `?:` not be used as a statement?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool IsPrint = false;

    IsPrint == true ? Console.WriteLine("Printing is allowed.") : Console.WriteLine("Printing is disabled.");
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Printing is allowed.")` is a *statement*. The ternary operator is used to evaluate either of two *expressions* based on a condition. `Console.WriteLine(IsPrint ? "Allowed" : "Not Allowed")` is permitted though.

Comment: As its name states, it's an operator. Operators take operands. Operands are value expressions. A statement is not an expression. You can't concatenate two Console.WriteLine() statements together using +, so it follows that you can't pick between two Console.WriteLine() statements using ?:.

Comment: And, besides, isn't `Console.WriteLine("Printing is {0}.", IsPrint ? "allowed" : "disabled");` cleaner than the code you posted?

Comment: @Enigmativity: You can also simplify the code with string interpolation `$"{...}"`.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. Why is it not allowed and would it be a good idea to extend the language by this feature? Would be very convenient for expression body methods.